# How to POST ajax and get response?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, response

I have a problem with a form, the post and the response. In my form I call a function (javascript) with the ajax post:

```
var vars = "test="+test;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: vars
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
}).fail(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

In index.php I receive all the data:

```
<?php
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    //do something
?>
```

After I have to give back a value to the previous php.
How can I do?? Thanks

Comment: So what issue you are getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var vars = "test="+test;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: vars
    success: function(html){
         alert(html)
    }
});
```

in index.php, enter follow code and check

```
<?php
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    //do something
    echo $test
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you send data back for any other HTTP request.

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");  # Avoid introducing XSS vulnerabilities
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple value you need to return, you can just `echo` it, and it will come back as the response.

If you need to return a more complex structure, you store it in a PHP array, say `$response`, and use `echo json_encode($response);` to output it back to javascript.

Comment: Don't `echo json_encode($response);` without `header("Content-Type: application/json")`. Without it, the code is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: I've always been doing this. If it's not too much to ask, could you link to a resource explaining why it's bad?

Comment: It allows an attacker to craft a link with embedded JavaScript in it that your code will turn in to something it tells the browser is HTML with embedded JavaScript in it. They then trick a victim into clicking on the link. The browser will then execute that code as if it was your code, with all the security privileges (access to cookies, access to local storage, ability to make XHR requests to your domain, etc) that implies.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

**Javascript**

```
var vars = { test : "test" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    data: vars,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.responseText);
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    echo json_encode($test);
?>
```

Try it and check console log

Comment: Don't echo user input back without `header("Content-Type: something/appropriate")` or HTML encoding the data. You'll open up an XSS vulnerability otherwise.

Comment: What is XSS? I usually use it and everything gone be OK but using header(...) only when I want to get data transaction with cross domain

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS

Answer (score -1):

If you have to return data in JSON format then use

```
echo json_encode($test);
```

Else you can simply echo the variable which you need in the ajax response. i.e.

```
echo $test;
```